# .data not returning value on first click

Tags: jquery

I stored value in .data method. It is not working on first click but working on second click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
var value=  $('div').data('key');
var txt= $(this).text();
$('div').data('key',txt)
$('span').text(value)
})})
</script>
```

// html

```
<div></div>
<a href="#">My text</a>
<span></span>
```

Comment: i can't see data-key attaribute...

Comment: @DipeshParmar data-key is not neccesary for using .data('key')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This should work* - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qtk5F/)

*On the first click you are tying to access the data before setting it.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var txt= $(this).text();
        $('div').data('key',txt)
        $('span').text($('div').data('key'))
    })
})
</script>
```

**Html**

```
<div></div>
 <a href="#">My text</a>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving it before you are storing it. Try moving `var value=...` to below `$('div').data(...`

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the data value before actually setting it

```
$(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    var value=  $('div').data('key'); // accessing data
    var txt= $(this).text();
    $('div').data('key',txt) // setting data
    $('span').text(value)
  })
})
```